# How can I improve Perl compare performance

Tags: perl

I have an array ref of about 50,000 users. I want to go through all those users and compare each one to all the others in order to build a weighted list of matches (if the name is an exact match it's worth x, a partial match is worth y etc).

After going through the list and doing all the checks, I then want to go get the 10 highest weighted matches. Here is sort of a example of what I'm doing to help explain:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
######################################################################
# Libraries
# ---------
use strict;
use warnings;

my $users = [];
$users->[0]{'Name'} = 'xxx';
$users->[0]{'Address'} = 'yyyy';
$users->[0]{'Phone'} = 'xxx';
$users->[1]{'Name'} = 'xxx';
$users->[1]{'Address'} = 'yyyy';
$users->[1]{'Phone'} = 'xxx';
$users->[2]{'Name'} = 'xxx';
$users->[3]{'Address'} = 'yyyy';
$users->[4]{'Phone'} = 'xxx';
foreach my $user_to_check (@$users) {
    my $matched_users = [];
    foreach my $user (@$users) {            
        $user_to_check->{'Weight'} = 0;
        if (lc($user_to_check->{'Name'}) eq lc($user->{'Name'})) {
            $user_to_check->{'Weight'} = ($user_to_check->{'Weight'} + 10);
        } elsif ((length($user_to_check->{'Name'}) > 2) && (length($user->{'Name'}) > 2) && ($user_to_check->{'Name'} =~ /\Q$user->{'Name'}\E/i)) {
            $user_to_check->{'Weight'} = ($user_to_check->{'Weight'} + 5);
        }
        if (lc($user_to_check->{'Address'}) eq lc($user->{'Address'})) {
            .....
        }
        if ($user_to_check->{'Weight'} > 0) {
            # We have matches, add to matched users
            push (@$matched_users,$user);
        }
    }
   # Now we want to get just the top 10 highest matching users
   foreach my $m_user (sort { $b->{'Weight'} <=> $a->{'Weight'} } @$matched_users ) {
    last if $counter == 10;
       .... # Do stuff with the 10 we want
    }         
}
```

The problem is, it's sooo slow. It takes more than a day to run (and I've tried it on multiple machines). I know that the "sort" is a killer but I did also try inserting the results into a tmp mysql table and then at the end instead of doing the Perl sort, I just did an order by select, but the difference in time was very minor.

As I'm just going through a existing data structure and comparing it I'm not sure what I could do (if anything) to speed it up. I'd appreciate any advise.

Comment: Is that actual code? Is `my $matched_users` really declared inside the inner loop? Do you know about algorithmic complexity (Big-O-notation)?

Comment: It wasn't in the right spot, sorry, I moved it. It should be in between the 2 foreach's

Comment: You could use a heap (priority queue) to make the sorting step faster.

Answer (score 15):

#### O(n²)

You compare each element in `@$users` against every element in there. That is 5E4² = 2.5E9 comparisions. For example, you wouldn't need to compare an element against itself. You also don't need to compare an element against one you have already compared. I.e. in this comparision table

```
  X Y Z
X - + +
Y - - +
Z - - -
```

there only have to be three comparision to have compared each element against all others. The nine comparisions you are doing are 66% unneccessary (asymptotically: 50% unneccessary).

You can implement this by looping over indices:

```
for my $i (0 .. $#$users) {
  my $userA = $users->[$i];
  for my $j ($i+1 .. $#$users) {
    my $userB = $users->[$j];
    ...;
  }
}
```

But this means that upon match, you have to increment the weight of both matching users.

#### Do things once, not 100,000 times

You lowercase the name of each user 1E5 times. This is 1E5 - 1 times to much! Just do it once for each element, possibly at data input.

As a side note, you shouldn't perform lowercasing, you should do case folding. This is available since at least v16 via the `fc` feature. Just lowercasing will be buggy when you have non-english data.

```
use feature 'fc'; # needs v16
$user->[NAME] = fc $name;
```

or

```
use Unicode::CaseFold;
$user->[NAME] = fc $name;
```

#### When hashes are not fast enough

Hashes are fast, in that a lookup takes constant time. But a single hash lookup is more expensive than an array access. As you only have a small, predefined set of fields, you can use the following trick to use hash-like arrays:

Declare some constants with the names of your fields that map to indices, e.g.

```
use constant {
  WEIGHT => 0,
  NAME => 1,
  ADDRESS => 2,
  ...;
};
```

And then put your data into arrays:

```
$users->[0][NAME] = $name; ...;
```

You can access the fields like

```
$userA->[WEIGHT] += 10;
```

While this looks like a hash, this is actually a safe method to access only certain fields of an array with minimal overhead.

#### Regexes are slow

Well, they are quite fast, but there is a better way to determine if a string is a substring of another string: use `index`. I.e.

```
$user_to_check->{'Name'} =~ /\Q$user->{'Name'}\E/i
```

Can be written as

```
(-1 != index $user_to_check->{Name}, $user->{Name})
```

assuming both are already <del>lowercased</del> case folded.

#### Alternative implementation

***Edit:** this appears to be invalidated by your edit to your question. This assumed you were trying to find some global similarities, not to obtain a set of good matches for each user*

Implementing these ideas would make your loops look somewhat like

```
for my $i (0 .. $#$users) {
  my $userA = $users->[$i];
  for my $j ($i+1 .. $#$users) {
    my $userB = $users->[$j];
    if ($userA->[NAME] eq $userB->[NAME]) {
        $userA->[WEIGHT] += 10;
        $userB->[WEIGHT] += 10;
    } elsif ((length($userA->[NAME]) > 2) && (length($userB->[NAME]) > 2))
        $userA->[WEIGHT] += 5 if -1 != index $userA->[NAME], $userB->[NAME];
        $userB->[WEIGHT] += 5 if -1 != index $userB->[NAME], $userA->[NAME];
    }
    if ($userA->[ADDRESS] eq $userB->[ADDRESS]) {
        ..... # More checks
    }
  }
}
my (@top_ten) = (sort { $b->[WEIGHT] <=> $a->[WEIGHT] } @$users)[0 .. 9];
```

#### Divide and conquer

The task you show is highly parallelizable. If you have the memory, using threads is easy here:

```
my $top10 = Thread::Queue->new;
my $users = ...; # each thread gets a copy of this data

my @threads = map threads->create(\&worker, $_), [0, int($#$users/2)], [int($#$users/2)+1, $#users];

# process output from the threads
while (defined(my $ret = $top10->dequeue)) {
  my ($user, @top10) = @$ret;
  ...;
}

$_->join for @threads;

sub worker {
  my ($from, $to) = @_;
  for my $i ($from .. $to) {
    my $userA = $users->[$i];
    for $userB (@$users) {
      ...;
    }
    my @top10 = ...;
    $top10->enqueue([ $userA, @top10 ]); # yield data to the main thread
  }
}
```

You should probably return your output via a queue (as shown here), but do as much processing as possible inside the threads. With more advanced partitioning of the workload, should spawn as many threads as you have processors available.

But if any kind of pipelining, filtering or caching can decrease the number of iterations needed in the nested loops, you should do such optimizations (think map-reduce-style programming).

#### Edit: Elegantly reducing complexity through hashes for deduplication

What we are essentially doing is calculating a matrix of how good our records match, e.g.

```
  X Y Z
X 9 4 5
Y 3 9 2
Z 5 2 9
```

If we assume that *X is similar to Y* implies *Y is similar to X*, then the matrix is symmetric, and we only need half of it:

```
  X Y Z
X \ 4 5
Y   \ 2
Z     \
```

Such a matrix is equivalent to a weighted, undirected graph:

```
4  X  5   |  X – Y: 4
  / \     |  X – Z: 5
 Y---Z    |  Y – Z: 2
   2      |
```

Therefore, we can represent it elegantly as a hash of hashes:

```
my %graph;
$graph{X}{Y} = 4;
$graph{X}{Z} = 5;
$graph{Y}{Z} = 2;
```

However, such a hash structure implies a direction (from node `X` to node `Y`). To make querying the data easier, we might as well include the other direction too (due to the implementation of hashes, this won't lead to a large memory increase).

```
$graph{$x}{$y} = $graph{$y}{$x} += 2;
```

Because each node is now only connected to those nodes it is similar to, we don't have to sort through 50,000 records. For the 100th record, we can get the ten most similar nodes like

```
my $node = 100;
my @top10 = (sort { $graph{$node}{$b} <=> $graph{$node}{$a} } keys %{ $graph{$node} })[0 .. 9];
```

This would change the implementation to

```
my %graph;

# build the graph, using the array indices as node ID
for my $i (0 .. $#$users) {
  my $userA = $users->[$i];
  for my $j ($i+1 .. $#$users) {
    my $userB = $users->[$j];
    if ($userA->[NAME] eq $userB->[NAME]) {
        $graph{$j}{$i} = $graph{$i}{$j} += 10;
    } elsif ((length($userA->[NAME]) > 2) && (length($userB->[NAME]) > 2))
        $graph{$j}{$i} = $graph{$i}{$j} += 5
          if -1 != index $userA->[NAME], $userB->[NAME]
          or -1 != index $userB->[NAME], $userA->[NAME];
    }
    if ($userA->[ADDRESS] eq $userB->[ADDRESS]) {
        ..... # More checks
    }
  }
}

# the graph is now fully populated.

# do somethething with each top10
while (my ($node_id, $similar) = each %graph) {
  my @most_similar_ids = (sort { $similar->{$b} <=> $similar->{$a} } keys %$similar)[0 .. 9];
  my ($user, @top10) = @$users[ $node_id, @most_similar_ids ];
  ...;
}
```

Building the graph this way should take half the time of naive iteration, and if the average number of edges for each node is low enough, going through similar nodes should be considerably faster.

Parallelizing this is a bit harder, as the graph each thread produces has to be combined before the data can be queried. For this, it would be best for each thread to perform the above code with the exception that the iteration bounds are given as parameters, and that only one edge should produced. The pair of edges will be completed in the combination phase:

```
THREAD A [0 .. 2/3]   partial
                   \  graph
                    =====> COMBINE -> full graph -> QUERY
                   /  partial
THREAD B [2/3 .. 1]   graph

# note bounds recognizing the triangular distribution of workload
```

However, this is only beneficial if there are only very few similar nodes for a given node, as combination is expensive.

Comment: Thanks Amon, I'm struggling a bit to understand what you are saying in the 1st part, I but I get the part from "When hashes are not fast enough" onward. I'm going to try to rewrite using your example, hopefully it will help me understand it better - thanks again!

Comment: What I don't really get is the 2 for loops, the 2nd one starts +1 from the first which I assume is to skip the current user I'm working on from the first for loop but don't I have to start over in the 2nd loop? In other words if I'm on the 100th user the 2nd loop starts with user 101 right? So if there were any matches in the first 100 then I wouldn't I miss those?

Comment: @Analog: You won't, because you've already checked those against the rest. There's no point in doing so again.

Comment: @Analog I draftet the alternative implementation before you edited your question. It is not fully appliccable here. If you can design your program in a way that remembering the result of a comparision is cheaper than performing the actual comparision, you can drastically reduce the number of iterations: If user A is in the top10 of user B, the reverse is also likely. But I don't know too much about the problem space you are trying to solve, so this is a bit of an XY-problem. There might be an even better solution waiting around the corner, but all I know is your code.

Comment: Sorry, now I'm a little confused - Yes, I am trying to come up with a specific list of "user to list of best match". So when they are looking at a specific user, I can say "these 10 looks like duplicates". Because of my edit can I not do the "looping over indices" now? Thanks

Comment: @Analog I added a way that uses the “compare once” shortcut and allows us to find the ten most similar nodes. It works by viewing the weight matrix as a graph, assuming that the weight matrix is sparse. I don't know your level of CompSci, so [Wikipedia on Graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics)) might help.

Comment: I'm trying to use your graph example, I'm doing all my checked to get my total weight then I'm adding that via $graph{$j}{$i} = $graph{$i}{$j} = $user->{'Weight'};, but the results I get are strange, I get all sorts of duplicate entries in the while. I assume that last line is saying "user checked and here is a array of the 10 matches), but that's not what I get.